# Get last two values after the zeros in decimal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to get the two values after the last zero in a decimal number.

I tried using .toFixed() and .toPrecision(), but I'm not able to achieve what I need.

I'm trying to achieve the following:-

```
let num1 = 0.028234234234234234
console.log(num1)
// 0.028

let num2 = 0.0000028234234234
console.log(num2)
// 0.0000028

let num3 = 0.0000000002823423
console.log(num3)
// 0.00000000028
```

But what I have is:

```
let num1 = 0.000002800
console.log(num1.toFixed(7))
// 0.000002800

console.log(num1.toPrecision(7))
// 0.000002800000
```

What is the proper way of achieving this without workarounds?

Comment: You want the first 2 digits that are not zero, I don't think theres a method without "workarounds". Namely, string mashing what you want.

Comment: See my answer that uses Intl.NumberFormat for a built in way to format numbers to 2 significant digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the others mentioned, I don't think there is one "proper" way of doing it. If that's for display purposes, you can go with a simple Regex replacement.

I don't know all of your test cases, but based on what you provided, something like the below could work:

```js
function format(num) {
  return num.toFixed(30).toString().replace(/(\d+)\.([0]+\d\d)(.*)/g, '$1.$2');
}

let num1 = 0.028234234234234234
console.log(format(num1))
// 0.028

let num2 = 0.0000028234234234
console.log(format(num2))
// 0.0000028

let num3 = 0.0000000002823423
console.log(format(num3))
// 0.00000000028

let num4 = 0.000000000000002823423
console.log(format(num4))
// 0.0000000000000028
```

Comment: Much clearer than mine. Nice answer.

Comment: All the answers helped, but yours did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "proper" way of doing this, because it isn't really a thing; you want an arbitrary precision of number based on where non-zeros appear.

I presume this is some sort of display thing, so it makes sense that this is done when you convert the number to a string to be displayed.

```js
function numberWithFirstTwoNonZeroDigits(input){
   var parts = input.toFixed(30).toString().split(".");
   var decimals = parts[1].split('').reduce((acc,i) => {
       if(acc.numDigits < 2){
          acc.result += i;
          if(i != "0") acc.numDigits++;
       }
       return acc;
   },{result:'',numDigits:0});
   
   return `${parts[0]}.${decimals.result}`;
}

let num1 = 0.028234234234234234
console.log(numberWithFirstTwoNonZeroDigits(num1))
// 0.028

let num2 = 0.0000028234234234
console.log(numberWithFirstTwoNonZeroDigits(num2))
// 0.0000028

let num3 = 0.0000000002823423
console.log(numberWithFirstTwoNonZeroDigits(num3))
// 0.00000000028
```

Answer (score 1):

First, calculate how many zeros are there after the decimal point.

```
const num = 0.0000000002823423;
const str = num.toFixed(20); // convert to string with 20 decimal places
const decimalIndex = str.indexOf('.');
const numZeros = str.slice(decimalIndex + 1).match(/^0*/)[0].length;
```

Here toFixed() is used to convert the number num to a string with 20 decimal places. This ensures that we capture all the zeros after the decimal point. Then, the indexOf() method is used to find the index of the decimal point in the string. The slice() method is used to get a substring that starts after the decimal point. The match() method with the regular expression /^0*/ is used to find a sequence of zero or more zeros at the beginning of the substring. Then using the length method we can get the number of zeros.

After that our job is pretty simple just add the 2 numbers you are keeping after the zeros.

```
const formattedNum = num.toFixed(numZeros + 2);
console.log(formattedNum);// 0.00000000028
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the answers of other people, there is a built in way to format numbers in JavaScript that will acheive what you want.

You should use the Internationalization API and the built in number formatting of [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat).

In the example below I use the locale `en` as this will guarantee that a period  is used as a decimal point.

By setting `maximumSignificantDigits: 2` limits the output to the 2 siginificant digits that you're after. Setting `maximumFractionDigits: 20` enables as many leading zeroes as possible.

**NOTE:** 20 is the maximum allowed value for `maximumFractionDigits` so if you're using numbers smaller than this you may run in to issues.

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en', {
  maximumSignificantDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 20
});

let num1 = 0.028234234234234234
console.log(formatter.format(num1))
// 0.028

let num2 = 0.0000028234234234
console.log(formatter.format(num2))
// 0.0000028

let num3 = 0.0000000002823423
console.log(formatter.format(num3))
// 0.00000000028
```

Comment: Just saw this now, upvoting. Thanks!